# vista multitasking dual monitor

Tags: multitasking-view

I use elementary os from the previous version (luna) and now I've installed Freya;
I really liked the way "luna" was managing workspaces, and I really don't like the way "freya" is doing it;

I've disabled "workspaces-only-on-primary" using dconf (org.gnome.mutter), but even now, the multitasking view only shows applications running on the first monitor (second monitor is simply empty while using it);
is there a way to make it work in both monitors and most of all to show in it all running applications in current workspace?

Comment: I too would like to know this. Let me know if you have already found a solution. Cheers!

Comment: unfortunally no news at the present day... I guess we'll have to wait for Loki and hope that it will be able to handle this again

Answer (score 3):

I see the same issue with Multi-Tasking view. 
Instead I have configured a hot corner to "Show All Windows" and it works beautifully across 2 monitors:
Applications -> System Tools -> System Settings -> Desktop -> Hot corners

Comment: I already have a hot corner to show all windows, but this doesn't allow you to manage workspaces; sometimes I need to move windows from one workspace to another; in luna the workspace manager was great and able to manage two monitors and the windows opened everywhere; freya is only able to see and move windows between workspaces on the first monitor (it doesn't see windows on the secondary monitor); since the system used by luna was perfect for me, I've been puzzled to see that a newer version has less functionality...